# Anything having mass has an equivalent amount of energy

Tags: relativity, units

The Wikipedia article on Mass–energy equivalence (i.e. $E=mc^2$) states

> "anything having mass has an **equivalent** amount of energy and vice versa..."

But how can we compare their amounts when the dimension of mass is $\mathsf{M}$, and the dimension of energy is $\mathsf{ML^2 T^{-2}}$?

Comment: Uh, the quite famous equation you have posted tells us exactly how we should compare them...? :) Each unit of energy is comparable to a unit of mass multiplied by $c^2$.

Comment: Yes, but the word "equivalent" confuses me. It would have been equivalent if it was $E=m$, I guess.

Comment: What's the problem? The dimension of $c^2$ is $\mathsf{L^2 T^{-2}}$. We often use units where $c=1$; in relativity, a distance of 1 light-second has the same magnitude as a duration of 1 second.

Comment: No, if $E = m$, they would be _equal_. The equivalence means (among many other things) that if you annihilate a particle of mass $m$ with its antiparticle at rest, you get energy in the form of gamma photons (other things are also possible), and the energy is equal to $E = 2mc^2$. The 2 comes from the fact that 2 particles were needed.

Comment: Which is how we know that if you combine one slug each of matter and antimatter (and get the intermix exactly right) you should release $2 \times 10^9$ lbf-ft of energy.

Comment: Oh, so it's only a matter of units (to compensate for our definitions of $\mathrm m$ and $\mathrm s$).

Comment: "Equivalent" here is a synonym for  "linearly isomorphic".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very confusing when you think of the dimensions, because what the mass energy equivalence is really about is that mass can be transformed into energy and vica versa, and that a certain mass really means a certain energy content.

> The mass–energy formula also serves to convert units of mass to units of energy (and vice versa), no matter what system of measurement units is used.

It is very important to understand that mass and energy are two names and two units for the same underlying conserved physical quantity.

> Thus, the laws of conservation of energy and conservation of (total) mass are equivalent and both hold true.[19]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass%E2%80%93energy_equivalence

Comment: For the willing https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/equivME/

Answer (score 0):

The $c^2$ in the formula turn things less clear. Unlike normal velocities, the speed of light in the vacuum is a constant, as $G$ or $h$.

Using year as unit of time and light-year as unit of length, c = 1, the meaningful relation is:

$E^2 = p^2 + m^2$

Energy can be seen as the hypotenuse in a rectangle triangle, where mass and momentum are the two other sides.

Light has no mass, so all energy is momentum. Bodies at rest in a given frame have only mass, and no momentum. Bodies moving in a given frame have mass and momentum.

Conservation of energy requires for example, that when a dynamite (at rest) explodes, the momentum immediately after the event be compensated by a decrease of mass.

Repeating the formula including $c's$ for dimensional consistency: 
$E^2 = c^2p^2 + m^2c^4$

When the body is at rest (no momentum):
$E = mc^2$